# How to create so much TextBoxes or labels in form (vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, char, label

[image: Problem Statement]

I need to display many independent chars on a form. The problem happens when there are about 1000 labels and the program crashes. Is there a light-weight container for chars?

Well, I need make a canvas like the picture. The trouble is that I also need to insert images at textbox and several lines mixed, but I just want to select some lines.

Comment: And who will read all those labels? Correct, nobody. As a general guideline: If you need to ask how to increase the possible number of visible controls, you are doing something very wrong. Ask yourself how to show relevant data in a meaningful way. You will be happier in the long run I recon.

Comment: And if you still want to show that much data, consider using a DataGridView with good sorting and filtering mechanics instead of single labels.

Comment: This is the only way to show that data, the problem is that a need process that data individualy, if I put all the chars in a textbox I can't select just the chars that I want.

Comment: Maybe make it clearer what you are trying to achieve in the first place (edit your question). That way you might get better tips how to do it better. You can add links to images and other people can include them in the question afterwards.